# Amazon Products API -Search all products from Amazon using API

Tags: amazon-mws, amazon-product-api

Looking for an official API from amazon, that can provide us products data, best sellers, trends, keyword research etc. from Amazon, specifically for print-on-demand (*Merch By amazon*) products. We want to provide amazon product search on our website.

There are two official API's provided by Amazon:

- **Product advertising API** - This is associated with affiliate account. Generated credentials to use for API access from authorized account, but still they do not provide response via API, unless the account holder qualifies for minimum revenue amount to amazon as affiliate. So this didn't help as our site is still in development and we cannot qualify for sales.
- **Amazon MWS** - this group of API are specific to Seller account. And our requirement is to get generalized products from amazon.

Neither of above API works. Did a lot of research to fulfill our requirements, and also check third parties available, but none provides detailed response as we need. There is much less info available for amazon product search, and no response from amazon on support tickets sent.

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 official not 2. There is also the SP API, and Ads API.

1. products data - MWS and SP have product data, not specific enough.
2. trends, keyword research, best sellers - not programmatically available via an Amazon API.

You best bet is Amazon's Product Opportunity Explorer or Brand Analytics data. Or you can use Jungle Scout or Helium 10

Comment: Yes, But the SP API is also for specific seller data. And our requirement is for all products on amazon site. Jungle Scout and helium 10 are useful but their API plans comes at much high cost